# How access properties of Inherited classes from abstract class

Tags: c#

I am working with a code in which there is an abstract class, e.g:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
   ...
}
```

and there are inherited classes from AbstractClass. One object is created depending on user input from one of inherited classes. Each inherited class has its own properties:

```
class classOne : AbstractClass
    {
         ...
         public int A { get; set;}
         public int B { get; set;}
         public int C { get; set;}
         ...
    }


class classTwo : AbstractClass
    {
         ...
         public int D { get; set;}
         public int E { get; set;}
         ...
    }
```

...
Say I want to use functions in that code and I know which object type would be returned. How can I modify the properties of the output object since the program is written in a way that the class of output is only determined when the program is run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know what concrete type you'll have, you can always cast your object:

```
var concreteObject = myObj as classOne;
```

Or, if you don't know what object type you'll have, you can test for it and then cast:

```
if (myObj is classOne) {
    // Cast to classOne and use
} else if (myObj is classTwo) {
    // Cast to classTwo and use
}
```

Hope this helps answer your question!

Answer (score 2):

If you know at runtime that an instance will be of a particular type, but you can't prove it to the compiler, you can cast it:

```
(SomeType)instance
```